# Paramatric curve that touches all integer $(x,y)$ points of the plane

Tags: geometry

**EDIT**: *After a partially correct answer, I slightly changed the question to better express it.*

In the 2D case we have that the parametric curve

$$x = \sin(\theta \cdot \pi)$$
$$y = \theta$$

touches every "integer" point $(x,0)$ ($x$ is an integer).

Is there a parametric formula for a 2D (or a 3D or multidimensional space) continuous curve that touches all integer points $(x,y), x,y \geq 0$ of the plane ?

In other words, two functions $f(\theta),g(\theta) $ such that for all integer points of the positive quadrant $(x,y), x,y \in \mathbb N$ exists $\theta$ such that $x = f(\theta), y = g(\theta)$

Something like [this curve on FooPlot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MiwiZXF4Ijoicypjb3MoMipzaW4ocypwaSkpIiwiZXF5IjoicypzaW4ocypwaSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNmZjAwMDAiLCJzbWluIjoiMCIsInNtYXgiOiI0cGkiLCJzc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d).

Or can it be proven that such formula cannot exist?

Obviously a curve exists: just "zig-zag" through the points of the positive quadrant ... and it can be defined in a set theoretic way:

$$\{ (x,y) \mid ((y=0) \land (2n\leq x \leq 2n+1)) \lor$$
$$((x=0) \land (2n+1\leq x \leq 2(n+1))) \lor $$
$$ ((x > 0) \land (y>0) \land (x+y=n+1)), n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

but I'm curious if a parametric formula can exist.

Comment: By parametric function, do you perhaps mean "smooth" curve?

Comment: @DanielV: preferably: I would like a solution that doesn't use the floor function (the Cantor pairing function suggested by Ross uses the floor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $z=\sin( \pi x y)$? It touches every integer point $(x, y,0)$, but also others like $(2,0.5,0)$

For your new question, you can use the [inverse of the Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function) to get $(x,y)$ as $f(\theta), g(\theta)$ as $\theta$ runs through the naturals.  Let $w = \lfloor (\sqrt {8\theta +1}-1)/2\rfloor, t=(w^2+w)/2,y=\theta -t, x=w-y$

Comment: ... Thanks, simple and clear ! ... it seems evident that I'm not a mathematician :-D :-D :-D

Comment: Do you think that a parametric equation exists? I.e. something like: do there exist functions $f,g$ such that for all $x,y$ integers there is a $\theta$ s.t. $x = f(\theta)$, $y = g(\theta)$?

Comment: I changed the question (perhaps now it is more clear what I'm looking for) ... probably there is a trivial answer also for this version.

Comment: You restricted it to the first quadrant, but your 1D example touches the negative integers, too.

Comment: Great! Do you think that  something could be achieved without the floor function?

Comment: There is a typo: $\sqrt{8 \theta - 1} - 1 \to \sqrt{8 \theta + 1} - 1$; a link to [the plot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MiwiZXF4IjoiZmxvb3IoKHNxcnQoOCpzKzEpLTEpLzIpLXMrKGZsb29yKChzcXJ0KDgqcysxKS0xKS8yKSpmbG9vcigoc3FydCg4KnMrMSktMSkvMikrZmxvb3IoKHNxcnQoOCpzKzEpLTEpLzIpKS8yIiwiZXF5Ijoicy0oZmxvb3IoKHNxcnQoOCpzKzEpLTEpLzIpKmZsb29yKChzcXJ0KDgqcysxKS0xKS8yKStmbG9vcigoc3FydCg4KnMrMSktMSkvMikpLzIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNmZjAwMDAiLCJzbWluIjoiMCIsInNtYXgiOiI0cGkiLCJzc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d)

Comment: I fixed the sign. You also have to subtract $1$ if you want to include the axes